# How can I eliminate the space below a horizontal line in res.cls after each section?

Tags: sectioning, resume

I'm currently working on my resume and I've been using the res.cls template from Michael DeCorte. I know it's a bit dated but it works fine for me (at least up until now).

I'm currently trying to add a horizontal line below each of the section titles. The original had a line below the address and phone numbers but no lines after that. This was written as (with some tweaking on my part):

```
\moveleft0.009\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\textwidth height .5pt}
```

The annoying thing is now I have a big space after this line before I get to the next line (company name and such). Of note, I don't have any issues in the sections that are followed immediately with \itemize.

So, for example, this is what I have for the experience section:

```
\begin{resume}
\section{EXPERIENCE} \smallskip
\moveleft0.009\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\textwidth height .5pt}
{\bf COMPANY NAME} \hfill {\bf DATES} \\
    {\sl POSITION} \hfill LOCATION
    \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
```

[image: Here is what the issue looks like. I would like to eliminate the space directly under the line.]

...and so on.

I've tried using \sectionskip=-0.5ex and such but it won't affect the sections I'm looking to change.

If anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it. I know I haven't provided too much information so let me know what would be beneficial for you.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\section{EXPERIENCE} {}
\vspace{-5pt}% adjust vertical separation
\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}\rule{\resumewidth}{1pt} % horizontal rule
```

[image: A]

I strongly suggest to use a modern class for writing CVs

Explore [CV in CTAN](https://ctan.org/topic/cv). Try for example [ModernCV](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv).

Comment: Thank you so much! Just for future reference: it looks like I needed to use \vspace both after the section heading and after the horizontal line.